# How to use Rails generate migration for adding a reference?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm currently using Rails 4.2.4. The thing is when I ran

`rails g migration AddCategoryRefToArticles category:references` command,

It generated the following migration

```
def change
  add_reference :articles, :category, index: true, foreign_key: true
end
```

that for some reason resulted `category_id` as integer field and not expected t.references.

```
create_table "articles", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.integer  "category_id"
end

add_index "articles", ["category_id"], name: "index_articles_on_category_id", using: :btree
```

Why is this so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`add_reference` is just a convenient helper to generate an integer field that follow the naming conventions to be used in an association. Since the `schema.rb` maps the database schema, it is expected that you see the specific data type rather than an higher level abstraction.

I'm not sure why you would expect a `t.references`, but your expectation is wrong. This is also explained in the [`add_reference`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_reference) documentation.

> Create a **`user_id` integer** column
>
> ```
> add_reference(:products, :user)
> ```

Comment: Ok, so how would it be different If I generated model instead? `rails g model Article category:references`

Comment: The `model` generator generates the model and the migration, whereas `migration` generates only the migration. Regardless which generator you use, the migration will be the same.

Comment: I mean when you generate model like in the above example, Rails create `t.reference` field

Comment: If you [`read the documentation`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/Table.html#method-i-references) you will understand they are exactly the same. Take some time to navigate the Rails documentation, don't make assumptions.